# If $a+b+c=0$ then what is the value of $a^2/ (ab-bc) +b^2/ (bc-ca) +c^2/ (ca-ab)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok I know that if $a+b+c=0$, then $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$.

I tried to rearrange the terms and bring it down in this similar form but to no avail.

Also I tried to separate the $\frac{a^2}{ab-bc}$ as $\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{a-c}$  and then writing $\frac{a}{a-c}=1-\frac{c}{a-c}$.

And then doing the same for others. 
And again I get stuck and can't get it to a simplified form. 
I have also tried other ways and the follow up result of
$a+b+c=0$ i.e. $ab+bc+ca=0$.

> Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take a moment and learn how to post mathematical content.

Comment: What is the source? If the question by any chance is $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\dfrac{a^2}{ab+ac},$$ then $$a(a+b+c)=0\implies\dfrac{a^2}{ab+ac}=-1$$

Comment: i can only see how to remove one variable here. Perhaps by some sorcery of many to one functions the thing simplifies further but i doubt it

Answer (score 0):

Let $c=-(a+b)$, substitute it and expand the above term. Then we obtain
$$
\frac{a^2}{ab-bc}+\frac{b^2}{bc-ca}+\frac{c^2}{ca-ab}=\frac{(a^3 - 3ab^2 - b^3)^2}{(2a + b)(a + 2b)(a + b)(a - b)ab}
$$

Comment: So is tjis your final answer or do i have to simplify it beacuse the answer has a numerical value

Comment: This can't have a numerical value. I fear that  lab bhattacharjee is right, and you missed something in this exercise. Did you check it?